# Is delegation of a calendar possible on using Office 365 and any client whatsoever on Mac?

Tags: macos, ms-office, calendar, office-365

I am looking for any way for OS X users to use Office 365's exchange calendaring service to delegate / share a calendar with another user on Office 365.

I have researched the [MS knowledge base](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-suite-help/turn-on-calendar-publishing-so-people-can-share-information-HA102892275.aspx?CTT=1) which states that for delegation, you need both an Exchange server (which I presume Office 365 is) and either Outlook 2010 or 2013 - neither of which run on OS X. If I have to, I could get to these software to temporarily sign in and set up the delegation, but I don't want to run Windows day in and day out and need a native OS X solution.

Short of running Windows virtually day to day, can OS X users use delegation features of Office 365?

Comment: Wondering why there would be a Microsoft Exchange on my MBA (in mail, Contacts, Calender) with os 10.8 if one could not use it ?

Comment: Please specif is it for internal use only (you have internal Exchange server), or is it the 365 web application.

Comment: Office 365 in my mind is a cloud only service, but I'll check your link and see if perhaps I need to narrow down the wording as you ask to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegate access is [available in Outlook 2011](http://tsd.gmu.edu/services/office365/training/delegates2011.cfm) but **not in Outlook Web App**, nor in Apple's Mail client.

Here are the instructions:

[How to set up 365 with Mac and Exchange server](http://tsd.gmu.edu/services/office365/configurations/Office-365-on-Mac.cfm).

Comment: What client on OS X allows delegation? Only Outlook 2011 is what I'm assuming you mean - but I'm not seeing the same screens as the help article with an Office 365 account.

Comment: QUOTE: OS X Lion (10.7) or later has built-in Exchange support to set up Mac Mail, Contacts, Calendar, Notes, and Reminders to work with your Office 365 account.

Comment: It looks like the only client that works with Office 365 is Microsoft Outlook 2011.